# Why the number of closed questions was increased in the last 30 day?

Tags: discussion, statistics

According to http://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/76890/statistics-about-the-site-questions, the number of closed questions were increased twice compared the previous maximum value that ocurred 9 months ago.

[image: Statistics about the site questions]

I'm wondering why occurred this. Are we closing obsolete questions? Do we have more new off-topic questions? Do we have higher standards than before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the increase is illusory, caused by [scheduled deletion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) of qualifying closed questions. Many closed questions are deleted in 9 days. Those that are migrated are deleted in 30 days. Deleted questions are not in the Posts table of Data Explorer, so the number of surviving closed questions from the previous months is much lower than for the current month.

Comment: Possible related query [Cliff questions (v2)](http://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/133171/cliff-questions-v2)

Comment: And there is another kind of cliff questions: [those with 1-2 delete votes already](http://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/207652/questions-with-most-delete-votes).